# Change the date in Excel from Text to date

Tags: excel, csv, date

I have several csv tables. By getting all the information from one column in seperate columns my date was seperated in day with month in one column and year in another. The problem is, that the date format in the day-month column is: "Apr 18", but when I click in the cell it stands by "01.04.2018".
When I want to change the format ridicolous numbers appears. Does anyone know how to fix it?
I want the european foramt: DD-MM-YYYY (18.04.2018)

Regards :)

[image: Date Problem in Excel]

Comment: Is the ridiculous number about 43000?

Comment: A better approach might be to change how you import the CSV document so that it is parsed correctly. A sample of your CSV document might be useful (as **TEXT** which can be copy/pasted into a csv file, not as a screenshot.)